# Android- Downloading Images occasionally fails.

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I am trying to download images from the net in my android application, it works most of the times but some pictures are failing to download and the Bitmap is null. The link to the images is always being there however. Any ideas what is causing this?

```
     private class GetImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

                int len = 500;

                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                    Log.v("url",urls[0]);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                            .openConnection();
                    connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                    connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    connection.setDoInput(true);

                    connection.connect();
                    int response = connection.getResponseCode();

                    inputstream = connection.getInputStream();
                    System.out.println(inputstream.toString());

                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputstream);
                    if(bitmap==null)
                        Log.v("Bitmap","fail");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (inputstream != null) {
                        try {
                            inputstream.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return "some string since it bitmap is sometimes null";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't always count on the network. You can use an http library like okhttp or volley that will allow you to do retries easily (or you could just retry yourself). Those libraries do a bunch of things to smooth out the http experience over using raw HttpUrlConnection.

Depending on how critical the image is, you could always hide the image in onPostExecute if it fails.

Comment: no it is the same images everytime, if I change the image it works fine. 
And I can't retry another library now, the deadline is close.

Comment: Though it is a JPG like all the others

Comment: Are you getting a particular Exception when you try to download those images?

Comment: Not at all. Which I find weird.

Comment: And if you go to the url from your browser, the images appear correctly?

Comment: Yes, and if I replace it with another link(to another image), it works fine.